# How can I ask for an input again instead of just having an error

Tags: java

So I want to ask the user for an input. The thing is that I also want the program to give an error message and ask for an input again if the user, instead of a number, try and type something that's not a number.

```
public class Mystuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Write your string");
        String s = SubProgram.string();
        System.out.println("The string: " +s);
        int i = SubProgram.getInt();
        System.out.println("The int: " +i);    
    }
}
```

Classes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SubProgram {
    private static final Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static String string() {
        String s = INPUT.nextLine();
        return s;
    }

    public static int getInt(){
            System.out.println("Write your number");
            int num = INPUT.nextInt();
            return num;
    
}
}
```

Comment: Put your prompt for input in a loop.  You stay in the loop until the user enters a valid value.

Comment: Did you ask this question earlier, such as earlier today (Sunday)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already been informed, use a loop, for example:

```
public static int getInt(){
    String num = null;
    while (num == null) {
        System.out.println("Write your number");
        num = INPUT.nextLine();
        if (!num.matches("\\d+")) {
            System.err.println("Invalid number supplied! (" + num + ")"); 
            num = null;
        }
    }
    return Integer.valueOf(num);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To repeat something, use a loop.

The basic pattern is:

```
 do {
    print a prompt;
    read input;
    validate input;
    if not valid, print error message;
 } while (valid input has not been provided);
```

A reasonable approach is to set some flag (say, `valid`) true or false in the "validate input" step, and then the loop is `while (!valid)`.

For use of `nextInt()`, it will throw an exception if the input is not a valid integer. You'll need to catch that exception (see `try-catch` statement) and use that to set "not valid".

```
  do {
      try {
         ..blah blah
         n = scanner.nextInt();
         valid = true;
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
         print error here;
         valid = false;
      }
 }  while (!valid);
```

I trust that, with these sketches of a solution, you can write the actual code.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have one more problem... When I try to return it always say that there is a problem. If I try to return inside the `try` it says `This method must return a result of type int` if I try to return after the `while` it says `num cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: All code paths need to return a value, not just the one inside the try inside the loop. If you want 'num' to be accessible outside the loop, you must declare it outside (before, in this case).  Next to read about: scope!